# 日本語に違和感: ヘルプセンター > 良い質問をするには?

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

ヘルプ センターの「良い質問をするには?」(https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) の文言に、おそらく日本語版のスタック・オーバーフローには合わないようなものが存在していました。

> 英語で書くのに自信がなければ、友達に校正を依頼します。

スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版は日本語で質問するサイトですから、最低でもここは「日本語」に置き換えなければいけないはずです。

ただ、わざわざ日本語非ネイティブの人がこっちに質問しに来るとも思えないので、単純に「英語で書くのに」の部分を削除するほうが私は良い気がします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

将来（パブリックベータから卒業するまで）ヘルプセンターの記事を全体見直す予定ですが、とりあえず「英語」を「日本語」に変えました。

英語からの直訳だったため、「スペリング」などもあまり日本語に当てはまらないですが、見直す記事が多くて、しばらく時間がかかります。

そして、英語で更新されたら、日本語も自動更新になってしまいましたので、最初の翻訳を実施した以降のヘルプセンターの記事が英語になってしまっている記事が多いです。

最近日本語版のヘルプセンターを独立した時、今から少しずつ英語を減らし、頑張って和訳しよう（もしくは一部を削ること）を考えています。